# How to use vapor for uploading/downloading image?

Tags: swift, image, server, vapor

Now: i am uploading data and saving it to my public folder:

```
let info = req.data
            guard let fileBytes = info["photo"]?.bytes
            else {
                var answerJson = JSON();
                try answerJson.set("success", "false");
                return answerJson
            }

            let dir = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.config.workDir).appendingPathComponent("Public/FleaMarketProductImages")
            let dirWithImage = dir.appendingPathComponent("test3.jpg")
            let fileManager = FileManager()
            let data = Data(bytes: fileBytes)
            fileManager.createFile(atPath: dirWithImage.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
```

Then on device for downloaing this file i am doing next:

```
 Alamofire.download(url).responseData { response in
            if let data = response.result.value {
                completionHandler(data)
            }
        }
```

I am getting some data, but when i do UIImage(data: data), i dont see my image. Where i did something wrong? Maybe there is another way to do it. And files in my public directory dont looks like image. They just files. Maybe do you know how to save it like an image????

Comment: Nobody knows?(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uploaded image will be one part of a multi-part request, so you need to use just the part that contains the image. `.bytes` will give you the whole request. I use:

```
guard let fileBytes = info.formData?["photo"]?.part.body
```

Or

```
guard let fileBytes = info?["photo"]?.part.body
```

if you aren't using a form.

Comment: Actually i didn't use form data for sending photo, but your answer helped me to understand a right way. I become using formData and it works great! Thank you!